# How do I store just a date in MS SQL from VB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, vb6

My project **requires I use VB (5 or 6)*** to store a date in an SQL Server database. The SQL datetime type includes the time, which I don't want. I'm also aware that VB's representation of a date doesn't mirror that of SQL Server.

So, how can I store a date held in VB's date type in the SQL database, as the datetime at midnight on that date, for example?

Edit: I need to use the date to select rows further down the line, so I can't get away with just truncating it on read.

*I know, I you were me, you wouldn't start from here. But given the constraints, any VB6/MS SQL fiends out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB6 has a [`DateValue()`](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/date-time-functions-visual-basic) function which returns the date portion of a Date/Time value, with the time portion "zeroed out". (Note: When the time portion of a date/time variable is "zeroed out", the time would be interpreted as 12:00 AM.)

Comment: If you pass DateValue() a VB6 Date, there will be an implicit conversion from date to string, since DateValue() expects a string, and then from string back to date. However both conversions will use the regional settings so it is safe. (Triggering implicit conversions can bite sometimes.)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 has [new date and time data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx). There is the "Date" data type if you don't want to store the time component.

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately I can't rely on having 2008 available at the customer site!

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTime column and just truncate the time at the presentation level.

Comment: Sorry, it forms part of the key, so I can't just change the view - I'll need to select on it, and not on a range of datetimes.

Comment: That doesn't matter: just make sure you always store a time of midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting and updating the date like this:

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@DateTime AS float)) AS datetime)
```

We have this in a UDF and it basically strips the time part from a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

In VB you can use the Date() function to return the current date with no time element.

If you an use an ADO Parameter object with a Command object then the OLE DB provider should handle the conversion of a VB Date type to the SQL Server DATETIME value.

In SQL Server (pre SQL 2008 DATE type) you should create a CHECK constraint on the column to ensure it is not possible to add a date with a time element (note I've used an unambiguous language 'safe' format for my DATETIME literals) e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD
   vb_date DATETIME NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT vb_date__no_time_element
      CHECK ((vb_date = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '1990-01-01T00:00:00.000', vb_date), '1990-01-01T00:00:00.000')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `DateSerial` to create the date you need.  You pass it a year, month and day and it gives you a date with midnight as the time.  You can then use it to pass as a parameter to an ADO command or similar.  When you read it, it will have midnight so that isn't a problem.  I like it better than DateValue as there is no string conversion.  If you really want you can create your own function like DateValue that uses DateSerial.

```
Function JustTheDatePlease(ByVal dtSource As Date) As Date

   JustTheDatePlease = DateSerial(Year(dtSource), Month(dtSource), Day(dtSource))

End Function
```

If for some reason you aren't using parameterized queries, and you really should have a good excuse for this, you can use the ODBC canonical form of a date in your queries.  You just format the date as `{d 'yyyy-mm-dd'}` for example `{d '2009-04-06'}`.